# 'cannot move location counter backwards' error on arduino

Tags: c++, tensorflow, memory, arduino, artificial-intelligence

I'm making face recognizer using arduino 33 ble board and teachble machine.
On the teacheble machine website, i put 10 pictures in class 1, 3 pictures in class 2, 5 pictures in class 3.
After model training, extracted files on tensorFlowLite tap, with TensorFlowLite for microcontrollers option.
When I uploaded code file to arduino on Arduino-IDE, I encountered this error message, 'cannot move location counter backwards'.
I found most people saying it's error about RAM.
they say "adjust your heap / stack memory size".
but i cant understand what they are saying.
someone said teachble machine's trained data is bad so you have to optimize it.

How can I optimize data or adjust memory size?
Could anyone help this poor helpless beginner?

This is .ino file, which i uploaded to arduino.

```
#include <TensorFlowLite.h>

#include "main_functions.h"
#include "image_provider.h"
#include "model_settings.h"
#include "person_detect_model_data.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_error_reporter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/version.h"

// Globals, used for compatibility with Arduino-style sketches.
namespace {
tflite::ErrorReporter* error_reporter = nullptr;
const tflite::Model* model = nullptr;
tflite::MicroInterpreter* interpreter = nullptr;
TfLiteTensor* input = nullptr;

// In order to use optimized tensorflow lite kernels, a signed int8_t quantized
// model is preferred over the legacy unsigned model format. This means that
// throughout this project, input images must be converted from unisgned to
// signed format. The easiest and quickest way to convert from unsigned to
// signed 8-bit integers is to subtract 128 from the unsigned value to get a
// signed value.

// An area of memory to use for input, output, and intermediate arrays.
constexpr int kTensorArenaSize = 136 * 1024;
static uint8_t tensor_arena[kTensorArenaSize];
}  // namespace

// The name of this function is important for Arduino compatibility.
void setup() {
  // Set up logging. Google style is to avoid globals or statics because of
  // lifetime uncertainty, but since this has a trivial destructor it's okay.
  // NOLINTNEXTLINE(runtime-global-variables)
  static tflite::MicroErrorReporter micro_error_reporter;
  error_reporter = &micro_error_reporter;

  // Map the model into a usable data structure. This doesn't involve any
  // copying or parsing, it's a very lightweight operation.
  model = tflite::GetModel(g_person_detect_model_data);
  if (model->version() != TFLITE_SCHEMA_VERSION) {
    TF_LITE_REPORT_ERROR(error_reporter,
                         "Model provided is schema version %d not equal "
                         "to supported version %d.",
                         model->version(), TFLITE_SCHEMA_VERSION);
    return;
  }

  // Pull in only the operation implementations we need.
  // This relies on a complete list of all the ops needed by this graph.
  // An easier approach is to just use the AllOpsResolver, but this will
  // incur some penalty in code space for op implementations that are not
  // needed by this graph.
  //
  // tflite::AllOpsResolver resolver;
  // NOLINTNEXTLINE(runtime-global-variables)
  static tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<6> micro_op_resolver;
  micro_op_resolver.AddAveragePool2D();
  micro_op_resolver.AddConv2D();
  micro_op_resolver.AddDepthwiseConv2D();
  micro_op_resolver.AddReshape();
  micro_op_resolver.AddSoftmax();
  micro_op_resolver.AddFullyConnected();

  // Build an interpreter to run the model with.
  // NOLINTNEXTLINE(runtime-global-variables)
  static tflite::MicroInterpreter static_interpreter(
      model, micro_op_resolver, tensor_arena, kTensorArenaSize, error_reporter);
  interpreter = &static_interpreter;

  // Allocate memory from the tensor_arena for the model's tensors.
  TfLiteStatus allocate_status = interpreter->AllocateTensors();
  if (allocate_status != kTfLiteOk) {
    TF_LITE_REPORT_ERROR(error_reporter, "AllocateTensors() failed");
    return;
  }

  // Get information about the memory area to use for the model's input.
  input = interpreter->input(0);
}

void loop() {
  // Get image from provider.
  if (kTfLiteOk != GetImage(error_reporter, kNumCols, kNumRows, kNumChannels,
                            input->data.int8)) {
    TF_LITE_REPORT_ERROR(error_reporter, "Image capture failed.");
  }

  // Run the model on this input and make sure it succeeds.
  if (kTfLiteOk != interpreter->Invoke()) {
    TF_LITE_REPORT_ERROR(error_reporter, "Invoke failed.");
  }

  TfLiteTensor* output = interpreter->output(0);

  // Process the inference results.
  int8_t person_score = output->data.uint8[kPersonIndex];
  int8_t no_person_score = output->data.uint8[kNotAPersonIndex];
  for (int i = 0; i < kCategoryCount; i++) {
    int8_t curr_category_score = output->data.uint8[i];
    const char* currCategory = kCategoryLabels[i];
    TF_LITE_REPORT_ERROR(error_reporter, "%s : %d", currCategory, curr_category_score);
  }
//  Serial.write(input->data.int8, bytesPerFrame);
}
```

this is arduino_main.cpp

```
#include "main_functions.h"

// Arduino automatically calls the setup() and loop() functions in a sketch, so
// where other systems need their own main routine in this file, it can be left
// empty.
```

this is image_provider.h

```
#ifndef TENSORFLOW_LITE_MICRO_EXAMPLES_PERSON_DETECTION_IMAGE_PROVIDER_H_
#define TENSORFLOW_LITE_MICRO_EXAMPLES_PERSON_DETECTION_IMAGE_PROVIDER_H_

#include "tensorflow/lite/c/common.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_error_reporter.h"

// This is an abstraction around an image source like a camera, and is
// expected to return 8-bit sample data.  The assumption is that this will be
// called in a low duty-cycle fashion in a low-power application.  In these
// cases, the imaging sensor need not be run in a streaming mode, but rather can
// be idled in a relatively low-power mode between calls to GetImage().  The
// assumption is that the overhead and time of bringing the low-power sensor out
// of this standby mode is commensurate with the expected duty cycle of the
// application.  The underlying sensor may actually be put into a streaming
// configuration, but the image buffer provided to GetImage should not be
// overwritten by the driver code until the next call to GetImage();
//
// The reference implementation can have no platform-specific dependencies, so
// it just returns a static image. For real applications, you should
// ensure there's a specialized implementation that accesses hardware APIs.
TfLiteStatus GetImage(tflite::ErrorReporter* error_reporter, int image_width,
                      int image_height, int channels, int8_t* image_data);

#endif  // TENSORFLOW_LITE_MICRO_EXAMPLES_PERSON_DETECTION_IMAGE_PROVIDER_H_
```

this is arduino_image_provider.cpp

```
#include "image_provider.h"

/*
   The sample requires the following third-party libraries to be installed and
   configured:

   Arducam
   -------
   1. Download https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino and copy its `ArduCAM`
      subdirectory into `Arduino/libraries`. Commit #e216049 has been tested
      with this code.
   2. Edit `Arduino/libraries/ArduCAM/memorysaver.h` and ensure that
      "#define OV2640_MINI_2MP_PLUS" is not commented out. Ensure all other
      defines in the same section are commented out.

   JPEGDecoder
   -----------
   1. Install "JPEGDecoder" 1.8.0 from the Arduino library manager.
   2. Edit "Arduino/Libraries/JPEGDecoder/src/User_Config.h" and comment out
      "#define LOAD_SD_LIBRARY" and "#define LOAD_SDFAT_LIBRARY".
*/

#if defined(ARDUINO) && !defined(ARDUINO_ARDUINO_NANO33BLE)
#define ARDUINO_EXCLUDE_CODE
#endif  // defined(ARDUINO) && !defined(ARDUINO_ARDUINO_NANO33BLE)

#ifndef ARDUINO_EXCLUDE_CODE

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Arduino_OV767X.h>

const int kCaptureWidth = 320;
const int kCaptureHeight = 240;
const int capDataLen = kCaptureWidth * kCaptureHeight * 2;
byte captured_data[kCaptureWidth * kCaptureHeight * 2]; // QVGA: 320x240 X 2 bytes per pixel (RGB565)

// Crop image and convert it to grayscale
TfLiteStatus ProcessImage(
  tflite::ErrorReporter* error_reporter,
  int image_width, int image_height,
  int8_t* image_data) {
 //  Serial.println("begging image process");
  //  const int skip_start_x = ceil((kCaptureWidth - image_width) / 2); // 40.5
  //  const int skip_start_y = ceil((kCaptureHeight - image_height) / 2); // 24
  //  const int skip_end_x_index = (kCaptureWidth - skip_start_x); // (176 - 40) = 135
  //  const int skip_end_y_index = (kCaptureHeight - skip_start_y); // 144 - 24 = 120
  const int imgSize = 96;

  // Color of the current pixel
  uint16_t color;
  for (int y = 0; y < imgSize; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < imgSize; x++) {
      int currentCapX = floor(map(x, 0, imgSize, 40, kCaptureWidth - 80));
      int currentCapY = floor(map(y, 0, imgSize, 0, kCaptureHeight));
      // Read the color of the pixel as 16-bit integer
      int read_index = (currentCapY * kCaptureWidth + currentCapX) * 2;//(y * kCaptureWidth + x) * 2;
      int i2 = (currentCapY * kCaptureWidth + currentCapX + 1) * 2;
      int i3 = ((currentCapY + 1) * kCaptureWidth + currentCapX) * 2;
      int i4 = ((currentCapY + 1) * kCaptureWidth + currentCapX + 1) * 2;

      uint8_t high_byte = captured_data[read_index];
      uint8_t low_byte = captured_data[read_index + 1];

      color = ((uint16_t)high_byte << 8) | low_byte;
      // Extract the color values (5 red bits, 6 green, 5 blue)
      uint8_t r, g, b;
      r = ((color & 0xF800) >> 11) * 8;
      g = ((color & 0x07E0) >> 5) * 4;
      b = ((color & 0x001F) >> 0) * 8;
      // Convert to grayscale by calculating luminance
      // See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale for magic numbers
      float gray_value = (0.2126 * r) + (0.7152 * g) + (0.0722 * b);

      if (i2 > 0 && i2 < capDataLen - 1) {
        high_byte = captured_data[i2];
        low_byte = captured_data[i2 + 1];
        color = ((uint16_t)high_byte << 8) | low_byte;
        r = ((color & 0xF800) >> 11) * 8;
        g = ((color & 0x07E0) >> 5) * 4;
        b = ((color & 0x001F) >> 0) * 8;
        gray_value += (0.2126 * r) + (0.7152 * g) + (0.0722 * b);
      }
      if (i3 > 0 && i3 < capDataLen - 1) {
        high_byte = captured_data[i3];
        low_byte = captured_data[i3 + 1];
        color = ((uint16_t)high_byte << 8) | low_byte;
        r = ((color & 0xF800) >> 11) * 8;
        g = ((color & 0x07E0) >> 5) * 4;
        b = ((color & 0x001F) >> 0) * 8;
        gray_value += (0.2126 * r) + (0.7152 * g) + (0.0722 * b);
      }

      if (i4 > 0 && i4 < capDataLen - 1) {
        high_byte = captured_data[i4];
        low_byte = captured_data[i4 + 1];
        color = ((uint16_t)high_byte << 8) | low_byte;
        r = ((color & 0xF800) >> 11) * 8;
        g = ((color & 0x07E0) >> 5) * 4;
        b = ((color & 0x001F) >> 0) * 8;
        gray_value += (0.2126 * r) + (0.7152 * g) + (0.0722 * b);
      }

      gray_value = gray_value / 4;
      
      // Convert to signed 8-bit integer by subtracting 128.
      gray_value -= 128;
      //      // The index of this pixel` in our flat output buffer
      int index = y * image_width + x;
      image_data[index] = static_cast<int8_t>(gray_value);
//      delayMicroseconds(10);
    }
  }
//  flushCap();
  //  Serial.println("processed image");
  //  Serial.println("processed image");
  return kTfLiteOk;
}
// Get an image from the camera module
TfLiteStatus GetImage(tflite::ErrorReporter* error_reporter, int image_width,
                      int image_height, int channels, int8_t* image_data) {
  static bool g_is_camera_initialized = false;
  if (!g_is_camera_initialized) {
   if (!Camera.begin(QVGA, RGB565, 1)) {

      return kTfLiteError;
    }
    g_is_camera_initialized = true;
  }

    Camera.readFrame(captured_data);

  TfLiteStatus decode_status = ProcessImage(
                                 error_reporter, image_width, image_height, image_data);
  if (decode_status != kTfLiteOk) {
    TF_LITE_REPORT_ERROR(error_reporter, "DecodeAndProcessImage failed");
    return decode_status;
  }

  return kTfLiteOk;
}

#endif  // ARDUINO_EXCLUDE_CODE
```

this is main_functions.h

```
#ifndef TENSORFLOW_LITE_MICRO_EXAMPLES_PERSON_DETECTION_MAIN_FUNCTIONS_H_
#define TENSORFLOW_LITE_MICRO_EXAMPLES_PERSON_DETECTION_MAIN_FUNCTIONS_H_

// Expose a C friendly interface for main functions.
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// Initializes all data needed for the example. The name is important, and needs
// to be setup() for Arduino compatibility.
void setup();

// Runs one iteration of data gathering and inference. This should be called
// repeatedly from the application code. The name needs to be loop() for Arduino
// compatibility.
void loop();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  // TENSORFLOW_LITE_MICRO_EXAMPLES_PERSON_DETECTION_MAIN_FUNCTIONS_H_
```

this is model_settings.cpp

```
#include "model_settings.h"

const char* kCategoryLabels[kCategoryCount] = {
    "test1","test2",
};
```

this is model_settings.h

```
#ifndef TENSORFLOW_LITE_MICRO_EXAMPLES_PERSON_DETECTION_MODEL_SETTINGS_H_
#define TENSORFLOW_LITE_MICRO_EXAMPLES_PERSON_DETECTION_MODEL_SETTINGS_H_

// Keeping these as constant expressions allow us to allocate fixed-sized arrays
// on the stack for our working memory.

// All of these values are derived from the values used during model training,
// if you change your model you'll need to update these constants.
constexpr int kNumCols = 96;
constexpr int kNumRows = 96;
constexpr int kNumChannels = 1;

constexpr int kMaxImageSize = kNumCols * kNumRows * kNumChannels;

constexpr int kCategoryCount = 2;
constexpr int kPersonIndex = 1;
constexpr int kNotAPersonIndex = 0;
extern const char* kCategoryLabels[kCategoryCount];

#endif  // TENSORFLOW_LITE_MICRO_EXAMPLES_PERSON_DETECTION_MODEL_SETTINGS_H_
```

this is person_detect_model_data.h

```
// This is a standard TensorFlow Lite model file that has been converted into a
// C data array, so it can be easily compiled into a binary for devices that
// don't have a file system. It was created using the command:
// xxd -i person_detect.tflite > person_detect_model_data.cc

#ifndef TENSORFLOW_LITE_MICRO_EXAMPLES_PERSON_DETECTION_PERSON_DETECT_MODEL_DATA_H_
#define TENSORFLOW_LITE_MICRO_EXAMPLES_PERSON_DETECTION_PERSON_DETECT_MODEL_DATA_H_

extern const unsigned char g_person_detect_model_data[];
extern const int g_person_detect_model_data_len;

#endif  // TENSORFLOW_LITE_MICRO_EXAMPLES_PERSON_DETECTION_PERSON_DETECT_MODEL_DATA_H_
```

omitted person_detect_model_data.cpp file. it's size is 3MB

I want to summarize or just extract error part, but i don't know where the error occurs, so i posted all the files. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the Arduino Nano 33 IoT (SAMD21G18A 48MHz, 256 KB SRAM, 1MB flash) does not provide the necessary resources that your application require.

You have two options:

Reduce the demands on the hardware by your application, e.g. by training the model with only one image and not with 18. You can gradually add more images to your training material until you get the error,

or

You need to get a larger hardware that can provide the necessary resources for your application.